# Creating a class to product subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering about how to design a nice class in order to produce a matplotlib plot suitable for my purpose. 
The first thing that I want to obtain is a class that could be callable as follows,
but I have no idea of how to design such a class.

This is how I want to use it:

```
fig,axs = MyClass(parameter...)
```

How can I properly use this?

**EDIT** Thank you very much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you give me a very good start point , my question now is since you show me how to pass the **parameter to the class, what do you think about how pass the list of variable in order to be plotted in `ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4` for example ? thanks again your help is always very precious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can't, or at least shouldn't. The return of a class should be an instance of itself.

However you may call a class, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, **parameters):
        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(**parameters)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.fig, self.axs

fig, axs = MyClass(figsize=(6,5))()
```

The drawback of this is that you directly loose any handler for the created class instance. This means that the above would be much simpler being written as function,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myfunction(**parameters):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(**parameters)
    return fig, axs

fig, axs = myfunction(figsize=(6,5))
```

So in order for the use of a class to make any sense, one would probably want to store it somehow and then make use of its attributes or methods.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, **parameters):
        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(**parameters)

myclass = MyClass(figsize=(6,5))
fig = myclass.fig
axs = myclass.axs
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to the other answer, you can also create a class that implements the `__iter__` function which emulates the class as a tuple, allowing it to return `fig, axs`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots()
        # Do stuff here
    def __iter__(self):
        for e in (self.fig, self.axs):
            yield e

fig, axs = MyClass(params)
```

However this is rather unorthodox, as described by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.

Comment: Upvote for the idea. Still wouldn't recommend using this concept in a real application though, so "unorthodox" describes it quite well.