# How to call the class to make the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

In reference to the post opened yesterday 
[In which I got very good feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545005/creating-a-class-to-product-subplots), I'm now starting to trying to develop the `Subplot` class, my idea is this:
the class `Subplot` should be a sort of wrapper, containing the style of the figure, color etc...

The user should interact with this class just specifying the number of plots `(nrow, ncols)` and `figzise` at the beginning, and then call some methods (called for example `plot`) using `axis[0,0].plot(value1,value2)`.
I'm still far away with the idea of how got this...

Now I want just to start initializing the class... but I get an error, here it is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

class Subplot :
    def __init__(self, ncols,nrows,figsize = (7,4.2),*params):
        #params     

        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,figsize)

        # Do stuff here

    def __iter__(self):
        for e in (self.fig, self.axs):
            yield e
```

and here it is the drive script for the class:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mysubplots 

def main():

   fig,axs = mysubplots.Subplot(2,2)
```

The error that I receive is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drivesp.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "drivesp.py", line 10, in main
    fig,axs = mysubplots.Subplot(2,2)
  File "/home/marco/Programming/Python/Numeric/OdeSystem/subplot/mysubplots.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,figsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1201, in subplots
    gridspec_kw=gridspec_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1328, in subplots
    (sharex, share_values))
ValueError: sharex [(7, 4.2)] must be one of ['all', 'row', 'col', 'none']
```

May somebody give me some hint... I'm a bit new with Python... this is also the reason why I don't think that I'm losing my time reinventing the wheel

Ok I figure out the first error:

```
class Subplot :
    def __init__(self, ncols,nrows,figsize,*params):
        #params     

        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,figsize=(7,4.2))

        # Do stuff here

    def __iter__(self):
        for e in (self.fig, self.axs):
            yield e
```

can I ask you some hint of how to proceed in order to interact with the class ?

I found a sed thing :P ... when I instantiate `fig,axs = mysubplots.Subplot(2,2,(8,5.5))`
`fig` and `axs` are not member of my wrapper `SubPlot`, so even thought I create a `style` function I cannot call using `axs` as istance of `Subplot`  How can I do ??

Comment: That's exactly the point on why you would not use this solution, as commented on the other question. If you do not have a handle for your class, you cannot use it. It's hence a one-time-only object, which is not very useful. Instead the answer from the other question provides an alternative.